# Trying to get the client-side code to successfully display the response message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I am new to js and i am encountering an issue: in my, for now simplified, login page I an trying to send a response back to the user if their email has not been found in the database. On the server side, i have:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    console.log('Email: ' + email);

    // Select the 'CosmeticsLawDB' database
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query('USE CosmeticsLawDB', (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) 
        {
          // The promise is rejected if an error occurs
          reject(error);
        } 
          else 
        {
          //The promise is resolved if the database is successfully selected
          console.log('"Clients" database selected');
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });

    // Check if the user exists in the 'Clients' table
    const results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE email = '${email}'`, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) 
        {
          reject(error);
        } 
          else 
        {
          console.log('The query was successful');
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });

    if (results.length === 0) 
    {
      console.log('User not found in the database');
      res.status(404).json({ status: 404, message: 'Your email has not been registered yet' });
    } 
      else if (results[0].password !== password) 
    {
      console.log('Incorrect password');
      res.status(401).json({ status: 401, message: 'Incorrect password' });
    } 
      else 
    {
      console.log('Login successful');
      res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', message: 'Login successful' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred during login:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: 'An error occurred during login' });
  }
});
```

and from the client-side code:

```
document.getElementById('login-form').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  //Get the values: email and password from the login form
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  //Create an object with the email and password
  var data = { email: email, password: password };

  //Send a POST request to the server with the data in JSON format
  var response = await fetch('/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

  //Get the response status
  var incomingResponse = await JSON.parse(response.text());
  var status = incomingResponse.status;

  console.log('Status: ' + status);

  //Display a message based on the response status
  if (status === 404) 
  {
    alert('Twój adres e-mail nie został jeszcze zarejestrowany. Proszę się zarejestrować.');
  } 
    else if (status === 401) 
  {
    alert('Invalid email or password.');
  } 
    else 
  {
    alert('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
  }
});
```

The point is that in the browser, when the server sends back the request, it is rendered as:

```
status  404
message "Your email has not been registered yet"
```

Not very beautiful. I am trying to get the client-side code to serve the user a message like alert indicating that their email has not been registered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this block of code

```js
  //Get the response status
  var incomingResponse = await JSON.parse(response.text());
  var status = incomingResponse.status;
  ...
```

I cannot understand how it can parse your response.text, as the text is given via a Promise, so it should be something like this

```js
  //Get the response status
  var responseText = await response.text();
  var incomingResponse = JSON.parse(responseText);
  var status = incomingResponse.status;
  ...
```